# Trying to put order on my html elements correctly

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to see my website elements in order.

I'm working on a school project, trying to be a little more ambitious than what was asked, which was actually pretty simple. Either way, I decided I was going to explore html 5 & css 3 further, and I'm trying to use stuff I didn't learn in class. With that being said, I made a website, where I have a main page and 4 more pages. I've finished the nav and the footer, so now I was working on one of the pages, the ZEN 4 page. When I added content to this page, everything looked just fine, but then I duplicated that content, just to see what would happen, and it appears with the footer on top, or it just hides the content behind the footer and leaves me with a scroll which is awful. I've tried to look into it on google, tried several "solutions", but nothing worked yet. Here's what I have so far:

HTML of the specific page I'm working on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>AMD ZEN 4</title>
    <meta name="author" content="José Júlio Ricardo Rodrigo" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Avb2QiuDEEvB4bZJYdft2mNjVShBftLdPG8FJ0V7irTLQ8Uo0qcPxh4Plq7G5tGm0rU+1SPhVotteLpBERwTkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favIcon/amdLogo.ico"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="arquitetura.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li onclick=esconderMenu()><a class="logo" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">José</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Júlio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ricardo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rodrigo</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="logo" href="index.html">AMD</a></li>
            <li class="esconderEmTlm"><a href="arquitetura.html">Zen 4</a></li>
            <li class="esconderEmTlm"><a href="sobre.html">História</a></li>
            <li class="esconderEmTlm"><a href="#">Ricardo</a></li>
            <li class="esconderEmTlm"><a href="#">Novidades</a></li>
            <li class="botaoMenu" onclick=mostrarMenu()><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="conteudoPrincipal_1">
        <article class="caracteristicas">
            <section>
                <table class="comparacaoZen">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ZEN/ZEN+</th>
                        <th>ZEN 2</th>
                        <th>ZEN 3</th>
                        <th>ZEN 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>14nm/12nm</td>
                        <td>7nm</td>
                        <td>7nm</td>
                        <td>5nm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>+52% IPC</td>
                        <td>+15% IPC</td>
                        <td>+19% IPC</td>
                        <td>+13% IPC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4-core</td>
                        <td>4-core</td>
                        <td>8-core</td>
                        <td>8-core</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8MB L3</td>
                        <td>16MB L3</td>
                        <td>32MB L3</td>
                        <td>32MB L3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4.35GHz max</td>
                        <td>4.7GHz max</td>
                        <td>4.9GHz max</td>
                        <td>5.7GHz max</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <section class="infoExtra">
                <h3>Novas características</h3>
                <p>ZEN/ZEN+ inovavam com a ativação de SMT, que permitia que um núcleo fosse capaz de executar 2 núcleos virtuais como uma só linha de execução. Além disso, trouxeram também um novo algoritmo de turbo. A ZEN 2, por sua vez apresenta um design novo "Chiplet Design". Por fim, o ZEN 4 acarreta uma nova topologia de memória cache L2 de 1MB e uma placa de vídeo integrada RDNA2 Graphics.</p>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section class="imagemProcessador">
            </section>
        </article>
        <article class="objetivo">
           <section class="esports">
            </section>
            <section >
                <table class="comparacaoZen">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ZEN/ZEN+</th>
                        <th>ZEN 2</th>
                        <th>ZEN 3</th>
                        <th>ZEN 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>14nm/12nm</td>
                        <td>7nm</td>
                        <td>7nm</td>
                        <td>5nm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>+52% IPC</td>
                        <td>+15% IPC</td>
                        <td>+19% IPC</td>
                        <td>+13% IPC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4-core</td>
                        <td>4-core</td>
                        <td>8-core</td>
                        <td>8-core</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8MB L3</td>
                        <td>16MB L3</td>
                        <td>32MB L3</td>
                        <td>32MB L3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4.35GHz max</td>
                        <td>4.7GHz max</td>
                        <td>4.9GHz max</td>
                        <td>5.7GHz max</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer"> 
        <div class="footerConteudo">
            <div class="footerAMD">
                <h3>AMD ZEN 4</h3>
                <p>Para alcançar um verdadeiro progresso, é necessário que a inovação pioneira e o engenho humano trabalhem em conjunto para criar algo excecional.</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="footerLista">
                <li><h3>Ligações</h3></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footerLink">AMD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footerLink">Lorem Ipsum1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footerLink">Lorem Ipsum2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="footerLista">
                <li><h3>Autores</h3></li>
                <li><p>José Silva</p></li>
                <li><p>Júlio Sousa</p></li>
                <li><p>Ricardo Matos</p></li>
                <li><p>Rodrigo Rodrigues</p></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footerRedes">
                <h3>Redes sociais</h3>
                <div class="footerRedesSociais">
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="instagram">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="facebook">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="whatsapp">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="footerRedesSociais">
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="instagram">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="facebook">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="whatsapp">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="footerRedesSociais">
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="instagram">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="facebook">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="whatsapp">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="footerRedesSociais">
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="instagram">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="facebook">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLink" id="whatsapp">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footerCopyright">
            &#169
            Projeto realizado para a Unidade Curricular de LP1 - ISEP - Ctesp DAS, Ermesinde         
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--EXPLICAR SCRIPT -> A função mostrarMenu é aplicada no último li da 2ª ul da nav que é um icon do menu burger, 
        e serve para mudar o estilo do menu para flex, abrindo-o pela lateral. A função esconderMenu, é aplicada no 1º li da 1ª ul
        e a sua função é de fechar este menu mostrado quando o icon burger é pressionado, sendo que neste caso, o esconderMenu 
        tem o formato de um X -->
    <script>
        function mostrarMenu(){
            const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
            menu.style.display = 'flex'
        }
        function esconderMenu(){
            const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
            menu.style.display = 'none'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

css stylesheet that comes with navbar and footer styling and some other things from main page that will be separated from this css later.

```
/*1 rem = 16px*/
/*margens e preenchimentos (margin & padding) têm 4 dimensões, na seguinte ordem top, right, bottom, left*/
/*se decidirem usar a short version ex: margin: 1rem 3rem, isto quer dizer 1rem em top & bot e 3rem em right e left*/
*{
    margin: 0; /*Os browsers vêm com diferentes margins e paddings predefinidos, dar reset a estes valores pode ser vantajoso*/
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*O default box-sizing é sempre content-box, o que faz com que quando definimos, por exemplo
    width: 300px;, e adicionarmos 20px padding, a width passará a ser 340px. Com border-box, ao definirmos 
    with: 300px; a largura manter-se-á a 300px independentemente de paddings ou margins */
    letter-spacing: 0.06rem; /*espaçamento entre letras*/
    text-decoration: none; /*Retirar qualquer decoração de texto, p.ex: sublinhados de links*/
    list-style-type: none; /*Retirar os pontos atrás dos elementos das listas*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; /*Importei o estilo de letra Poppins, porque curti, se quiserem alterar força!*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body{
    min-width: 100vw;  /* 1vw é relativo a 1% da largura da janela de exibição, ou seja, 100vw = 100% || resize na janela, ela adapta*/
    min-height: 100vh; /* 1vh é relativo a 1% da altura da janela de exibição, ou seja, 100vh = 100% || resize na janela, ele adapta*/
   /*background-image: url(backgroundImage/background2.jpg); Adicionar uma imagem ao bg do body*/
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover; /*Cobre todo o bg*/
    background-position: center; /*Centra a imagem do bg*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Sem repetição de imagem*/
    position: relative;
}
h1{
    font-size: 2.3rem; 
    font-weight: 500;
}
h3{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}
a{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}
/*ESTILIZAÇÃO DOS MENUS*/
nav{
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 1.625rem;
}
nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /*Apresenta todos os li's numa disposição horizontal dentro da nav*/
    justify-content: flex-end; /*Posiciona todos os items no final da nav*/
    align-items: center; /*Centra todos os items da nav em altura*/
}
nav li{
    height: 3.125rem; /*Define a altura dos li, e como não foi definida nenhuma altura na nav, dita a altura da mesma também*/
}
nav a{
    height: 100%; /*Define a altura dos links da nav como 100%, mantendo-as na posição central da mesma*/
    padding: 0 2rem; /*preenchimento para a direita e para a esquerda em todos os items da nav*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000001;
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: #000001;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}
.logo{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: 0.12rem 0.12rem rgba(3, 62, 4, 0.542);
}
.logo:hover{
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
nav li:first-child{
    margin-right: auto; /*encosta o logótipo totalmente à esquerda, excluindo o preenchimento*/
}
/*Menu Mobile/Tablet*/
.menu{
    position: fixed; /*fixa a posição do menu num ponto*/
    top: 0; /*define o começo do menu totalmente no topo*/
    right: 0; /*e totalmente à direita*/
    height: 100vh; /*faz com que seja visível em toda a altura da página web*/
    width: 15.6rem; /*mas em apenas 15.6rem de largura*/
    z-index: 999; /*Z-Index = 999 faz com que o elemento fique sempre acima dos outros elementos (z seria dimensão profundidade)*/
    background-color: #f5f5f575; /*cor neutra com alguma transparência para combinar com o desfocado*/
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /*adiciona um efeito desfocado ao menu */
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px #f5f5f5; /*adiciona um pequeno efeito de sombra branco*/
    display: none; /*faz com que, por definição, em ecrãs grandes este menu não esteja disponível*/
    flex-direction: column; /*coloca os elementos abaixo uns dos outros, ao invés de lado a lado*/
    justify-content: flex-start; /*fixa os links do menu, no top do menu, caso contrário ficariam colados à parte de baixo do mesmo*/
}
.menu li{
    width: 100%; /*elementos do menu com width a 100%, utilizam toda a largura do mesmo, enconstando-se assim à esquerda (exceto preenchimento)*/
}
.botaoMenu{
    display: none;
}
/*RESPONSIVIDADE DOS MENUS*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .esconderEmTlm{

        display: none; /*Aqui estamos a dizer que todos os elementos do nosso html que receberem esta classe, não estarão visíveis em 
                        dispositivos com até 800px de largura*/
    }
    .botaoMenu{ 
        display: block; /*fazer com o que nosso menu hamburguer apareça no canto superior direito*/
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .menu{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
/*Estilização BASE da main, conteúdos exclusivos da 1ª página serão estilizados abaixo do footer*/
.main{
    width: 100vw; /*nosso conteúdo principal ocupará 100% da largura*/
    height: 88vh; /*porém apenas 88% da altura, visto que reservamos 12% para o header, e o footer aparecerá quando dermos scroll na
                    página.*/
}
/*ESTILIZAÇÃO DO FOOTER*/
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
}
.footerConteudo{
    background-color: rgb(59, 39, 39);
    display: grid; /*define o footer num contentor com formato tabela*/
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /*define que as tabelas terão formato coluna, e que se vão formar 4 colunas, com o mesmo tamanho*/
    padding: 2rem 10rem; /*preenchimento entre colunas*/
}
.footerAMD h3{
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.footerAMD p{
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.footerAMD{
    gap: 1rem; /*gap é espaço que separa elementos de uma tabela, funciona quase como line-spacing só que específico para linhas/colunas de tabela, embora também possa ser utilizado para line spacing*/
}
.footerRedesSociais{
    display: flex; /*alinha os elementos frente a frente*/
    gap: 2.5rem; /*espaço entre os elementos*/
    margin-top: 1rem; /*afastar do conteúdo acima*/
}
.footerRedesSociais .footerLink{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    color: azure;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
/*este bloco de estilização serve para colocar os icons das redes sociais dentro de um pequeno círculo e centralizá-los dentro do mesmo, bem como definir o tempo de transição da opacidade*/
}
.footerRedesSociais .footerLink i{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.footerRedesSociais .footerLink:hover{
    opacity: 0.8; /*quando se passa o rato em cima de links no footer, a sua opacidade diminui ligeiramente*/
}
#instagram{
    background: linear-gradient(#7f37c9, #ff2992, #ff9807);
}
#facebook{
    background-color: #4267b3;
}
#whatsapp{
    background-color: #25d366;
}
/*nos blocos acima, atribuir as cores das respetivas redes aos círculos*/
.footerLista{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /*deixa os elementos da lista em formato coluna (uns embaixo dos outros)*/
    gap: 1.5rem; 
}
.footerLista h3{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.footerLista p{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.footerLista a{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.footerRedes h3{
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.footerCopyright{
    background-color:rgb(59, 39, 39);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
/*RESPONSIVIDADE FOOTER*/
@media screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        gap: 15rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1536px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        gap: 6rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        gap: 6rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        gap: 3rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /*aqui deixam de ser 4 colunas no footer e passam a ser duas, visto que o ecrã já é demasiado pequeno para as 4*/
        gap: 2rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 426px) {
    .footerConteudo{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); /*aqui trata-se de um telemóvel ou algo do género, pelo que terá que haver apenas 1 coluna*/
        padding: 3rem 2rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    *{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
/*Aqui começa o conteúdo exclusivo da 1ª página*/
.arquiteturaZen{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.arquiteturaZen h2{
    font-size: 6rem;
}
.arquiteturaZen p{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.zen4Introducao p{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.botaoDescobreMais{
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding: 0.6rem;
}
.arquiteturaZen{
    margin-top: 0;
    background-image: url(imagens/mundo.jpg);
    background-size: cover; /*Cobre todo o bg*/
    background-position: center; /*Centra a imagem do bg*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    
}
figure{
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;    
}
img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}
.contentorGrelha p{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and this is the specific css stylesheet for the page I'm working on rn

```
.conteudoPrincipal_1{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 88vh;
}
.caracteristicas{                                       /*1º Bloco de Conteúdo*/
    width: 95vw;
    height: 55vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    position:static;
}
.comparacaoZen{
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(133, 121, 147, 0.455);
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    
}
.comparacaoZen th, td{
    border: 0.2rem solid #381e1e;
    text-align: center;
}
.infoExtra{
    background-color:#381e1e;
    line-height: 1rem;
}
.infoExtra h3{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.infoExtra p{
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}
.imagemProcessador{     
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;    
    background-image: url(imagens/processador.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}                                                    /*Fim do 1º Bloco de Conteúdo*/
.objetivo{
    width: 95vw;
    height: 50vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 6rem 0 6rem 0;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    position:static;
}
.esports{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    background-image: url(imagens/esports.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .caracteristicas{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
    .objetivo{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
}
```

and also, this is what I see...
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Can you reduce it to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem, please?

Comment: However, when you get a problem with HTML, it is often a good idea to use a checker, for example the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) shows several errors.

Comment: Hello. I want my website to just show the elements normally, like, the footer on the bottom of the page, and if the screen height isn't enough for me to see everything, I want to scroll, see the rest of the content nicely, and only after all that, the footer would show. I'm making a website about ZEN 4, so, for example, take a look at this: https://www.amd.com/en.html . There you have a whole bunch of content, you scroll down, you see more content, and in the bottom you have the footer. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining perfectly, I'm not native speaker. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you have to mess around a bit to fix that. If you change your ``main`` element's width to 99vw instead of 100vw, you will see it gains its OWN scrollbar because it's height exceeds the available height, producing the behaviour you're seeing. You would need to remove the set ``height`` property from ``main``, and then with JS, check if the scroll is at the bottom of the page, only then expand the footer. The example code was not designed for what you want.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can fix this without using JS? My teacher said he doesn't want us to use that, I just built a very small script to enable/disable a burger menu so far.

Comment: I don't see why he'd have to dynamically expand the footer. The footer naturally exists at the bottom of the page so you'd see it when you scroll to the bottom.
Just remove the height in the CSS as mentioned as it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious from your question what the exact issue is with your page. I appreciate you're not a native English speaker though, so have made a best guess.

Judging by the page you linked in the comment, you want your page as one single scrolling unit, rather than what you have now which is where the  section scroll separately to the whole page.

This is caused by the height being set to a viewport value in:

```css
.conteudoPrincipal_1 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 88vh;
}
```

This is causing your  element to be restricted in height and scroll to fit the content. You then have your main page scroll around that to include the footer.

If you remove the `height:88vh` then it should scroll as the AMD page does.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you , that pretty much does it. But I have another doubt, as you can see clearly on the 2nd image I uploaded, my 2nd table has a scrollbar, and the image doesn't have the same height as the other one, even tho the css is exactly the same for both. Why does this happen?

Comment: NVM! Solved, thanks a lot, pretty simple wasn't it lol... Still pretty new to this.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it! :) We were all new at one time, you'll get there!